# Trying to create a REst Service using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

I am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#first) tutorial to create a REst Service using Jersey.

Sometimes i fail to understand fully what the author of the tutorial means but these are the steps that i have followed so far :

**1)** *Created a dynamic web project and named it* : *`de.vogella.jersey.first`*

**2)** *Installed Maven dependencies on eclipse*

**3)** *Converted my project to a Maven project (that means created a pom.xml file)*

**4)** *Added the necessary dependencies in `pom.xml` so that i can use jersey without having to manually add the jar files. I added the following xml :*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**5)** *The author suggests to create a java class and gives some code. I can only assume that he wants us to create a new package in the src folder , name it `de.vogella.jersey.first` and then create a java class and name it `Hello` and place the code there. Thats what i did.*

**6)** *Then he suggests to open the `web.xml` file. Theres not such a file in the project though. So i go ahead and create such a file in the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` path. I place the code that he suggest.*

**7)** *Next is the step that i fail to understand most. He talks about the `web.xml` that we just added and more specifically he states:*

**"The parameter "com.sun.jersey.config.property.package" defines in which package jersey will look for the web service classes. This property must point to your resources classes. "**

**8)** *Last step is open the URL `http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello` in my browser. However i get `HTTP Status 404 - /de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello`*

---

With what shall i replace exactly the `com.sun.jersey.config.property.package` ?

Are the steps that i have followed till now correct , or i misinterpreted something?

Comment: The web.xml file goes in `WebContent\WEB-INF` *not* in `lib`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The property `com.sun.jersey.config.property.package` just needs to be set as the package that contains the web service classes. In the tutorial it is `de.vogella.jersey.first`, and you can see that the `Hello` class is declared under that package.

In other words, when you deploy the application, Jersey will look for web service classes in the package `de.vogella.jersey.first`, and in this case it will find the class `Hello` being declared with the `javax.ws.rs.Path` annotation, and create a web service endpoint listening on the URL that has been declared with `@Path`.

However, I have never set such a thing for my Jersey projects. I just put my web service classes in the `src` folder, and Jersey recognizes them no matter which package I put them inside. This is the minimum configuration that I have with Jersey projects in `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <!-- 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.webservice.classes</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    -->

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also if you do not fancy Maven projects, just create a simple Dynamic Web Project and copy the [Jersey JARs](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#core_server) to `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Also, as [Qwerky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443515/qwerky) suggested, `web.xml` has to be in `WebContent/WEB-INF/` and `.jar` files should be copied to `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Other than that, the described procedure looks fine!

Comment: Well , what i did was include manually the Jersey Jar files and not use the Maven dependencies. Actually i also needed to include the jersey-servlet.jar found here: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3a%22com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer%22 . I also replaced the com.sun.jersey.config.property.package with my package where my java classes are. please update your answer with these info and i ll accept it. Also the xml you provided has some errors? I thing the servlet-mapping tags should be inside the servlet tags right?

Comment: @DonP I think the provided `web.xml` is fine. Take a look at the tutorial, chapter `5.3. Define Jersey Servlet dispatcher`: `<servlet-mapping>` is defined after `<servlet>`!

Answer (score 13):

For information if you are using Jersey 2 this class has been replaced with `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` so your resource configuration would be like:

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.todo.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: I was confused over this as in the given web.xml the author used property `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` while in the description it speaks about `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages`. Your answer cleared it..