# Jersey always returning 404

Tags: java, jersey, web.xml

I have builded a Project for praticting and learning and testing,there are no error in the code,but no matter how hard I tried,I can't figure out the URI path which is GET method in testGet.java,that's a test page,and I always get the 404 error,I have searched Google for a few hours,but I didn't find the answer.my code is here 
https://github.com/abcdef123ghi/jerseytest

here is my web.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app 
  PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN'
  'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd'>
<web-app>
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Restful Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Restful Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my testGET.java

```java
package service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/test")
public class testGet {

    @GET
    //@Path("/test")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=utf-8"})
    public String Hello()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Question

Does anyone have worked with something related?
I'm doing something wrong?
I think that this could be a bug, when working with more then one @Path, one in the Class and other in the Method.
Any tips is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: What URL are you using that returns a 404 status?

Comment: thanks for replying me

Comment: Your web.xml configuration is bad. You are using Jersey 1.x configuration, but you are using Jersey 2.x jars.  Look at the [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2) for the correct configuration

Comment: I have tried http://localhost:8080/webapi/test/test/    http://localhost:8080/webapi/test/    http://localhost:8080/service/webapi/test/    http://localhost:8080/service/webapi/test/test, they all doesn't work

Comment: Check your server log (at the time of server startup) for errors. Might be, that deployment of your application fails.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `Maven` for dependencies ? If not, I would recommand you to use it, it will make your life way easier !

One thing that we can point out is that you are using `jersey 2.19`. However, in your `web.xml`, you are using

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Restful Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

which is the from `jersey 1.x`. In the `jersey 2.x`, it has been changed to :

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Restful Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Then try also to add your `.jar` into `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16232316/5147609))

However, your `testGet.java` should be correct (Note that I would rename it to `TestGet.java`).
You should be able when you launch your service to access with :
`http://host:port/rest/test`

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL would be:

```
http://{server}:{port}/{context-root}/{servlet-mapping}/{path}
```

In your example:

- `{server}` = `localhost`
- `{port}` = `8080`
- `{context-root}` = `service`? (usually the name of the war file)
- `{servlet-mapping}` = `webapi`
- `{path}` = `test`

So it should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/service/webapi/test
```

If the URL is not available, then probably the deployment failed. Check your server log (for the time of deployment of the war file).